# How to make font text clickable?

Tags: java, libgdx

My game has 3 `BitmapFont` (later more) on screen. I Want to be able to touch the font and output it's string in the console so I know which one is pressed. I tried to create a rectangle but I was unable to get the string of the touched `BitmapFont`.

Here is my code to create `BitmapFont`:

```
public class simple  implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;
    GlyphLayout layout;
    String a1 = "aa";
    String a2 = "bb";
    String a3 = "cc";
    int a = 0;
    @Override
    public void create() {
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      layout = new GlyphLayout();
      font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("arial-15.fnt"));
   }
   @Override
   public void render() {
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);    
      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
      batch.begin();
      for (int i =1; i< 4;i++){ 
          layout.setText(font, "a"+i);
          font.draw(batch, layout,200+(15*i),200 );
      }
      batch.end();  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for editing help

Comment: you  go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996693/how-to-use-bitmap-font-as-scene2d-actor/34996980#34996980 for your answer.

Comment: I want to get some button for string a1; a2; a3 for each; then when user click it , it should show the string value . Like when I pressed bitmapfont a1 it show "aa" in console; and one more problem is it did not draw string vlaue it just draw a1 not "aa" plz give me write code to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have combined functionality of String, BitmapFont, Layout and positioning. The best way is to create a `class` for this clickable font that contains all that we need. I did some work for you since I am a nice guy and I actually have plenty of other things to do :D.

```
public class ClickableFont {

//Declare the fields
private GlyphLayout layout;
private BitmapFont font;

private String text;

private int posX;
private int posY;

/**
 * Constructs clickable text from a font
 * @param text Text to display
 * @param posX X position of the text
 * @param posY Y position of the text
 */
public ClickableFont(String text, int posX, int posY) {
    this.text = text;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("arial-15.fnt"));
    layout = new GlyphLayout(font, text);

}

/**
 * @param batch Draws the text using the given SpriteBatch.
 * @param camera Requires a camera to calculate touches between screen and world.
 */
public void update(SpriteBatch batch, OrthographicCamera camera)
{
    checkClicked(camera);

    font.draw(batch, layout, posX, posY);
}

/**
 * Checks if this object is clicked and outputs to console
 * @param camera the camera
 */
private void checkClicked(OrthographicCamera camera)
{
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
    {
        //Get screen coordinates
        Vector3 touch = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        //Transform screen touch to world coordinates using the camera you are drawing with
        camera.unproject(touch);

        //System.out.println(getRectangle());
        //System.out.println(touch);

        if (getRectangle().contains(touch.x, touch.y))
        {
            System.out.println(text + " has been clicked.");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a rectangle for the sprite to perform collision calculations.
 * Since it seems font.draw draws from top to bottom (coordinate system of LibGDX is not consistent)
 * We have to adept the rectangle position Y position
 * @return rectangle of font bounds
 */
private Rectangle getRectangle()
{
    return new Rectangle(posX, posY - (int)layout.height, (int)layout.width, (int)layout.height);
}
}
```

As you can see it tackles your problem in steps. Tackling problems is all you are doing in programming. A rule of thumb is to never make a method more then 10 lines, excluding comments. Exceptions can be made but any large method can be broken down into much more readable smaller methods.

Now how to use this ClickableFont class?

```
    public class simple  implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    //folowing are not nececary anymore since it's handled by the new class
    //BitmapFont font; 
    //GlyphLayout layout; 
    //String a1 = "aa";
    //String a2 = "bb";
    //String a3 = "cc";

    int a = 0;

    //Declare a list to hold your clickable fonts
    List<ClickableFont> clickableFonts = new ArrayList<ClickableFont>();

    @Override
    public void create() {
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();

    //Add clickable fonts to the list
      clickableFonts.add(new ClickableFont("aa", 200, 200));
      clickableFonts.add(new ClickableFont("bb", 200 + 150, 200));
      clickableFonts.add(new ClickableFont("cc", 200 + 150 * 2, 200));
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);    
      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
      batch.begin();
      /* replace your loop
      for (int i =1; i< 4;i++){ 
          layout.setText(font, "a"+i);
          font.draw(batch, layout,200+(15*i),200 );
      }*/
      for (ClickableFont font : clickableFonts)
      {
          font.update(batch, camera);
      }
      batch.end();  
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry now I read your question again I see I miss understood it. I cleaned up your question and will change my answer.

Comment: My problem is this I got 40 strings ; want to draw them and if someone touch it ; then it show the selected text in console .

Comment: @YanGodara That is what the class is doing. You add `ClickableFont` objects to a list specifying the text to display and position. Then iterate over the list and `.update()` them. Within the update it draws the text and it check for clicks and outputs the text to console once clicked.

Comment: Will u plz tell me how to add this to stage ; I usally create a" void draw and add (font.draw()) in it" and call stage.draw() in render .how to add all these text to stage .

Comment: A `BitmapFont` is not an actor and thus cannot be added to the stage. If you want to have a clickable font on the stage you should have asked that at first since all you need to have for that is a TextButton. You create a textbutton, give it a font and text, add a clicklistener and add it to the stage.

Comment: @YanGodara I strongly suggest you read this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d and https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for this sample that helps me ; I improve it a little bit with callable cf https://github.com/boly38/pocgdx/blob/main/core/src/com/olity/pocgdx/ui/tools/ClickableFont.java